# How to configure the left-bar menu with sub menus in admin-on-rest?

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I would love an example of how to configure the admin-on-rest left-bar menu with sub-menus.

Documentation:
https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Admin.html#menu

Comment: Do you mean cascading menus such as the "Nested menus" sample in [material-ui doc](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/menu) ?

Comment: Yes! I want that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported out of the box in aor. However, you should be able to make your own menu and integrate material-ui sub menus in it. There's nothing special about it. Remember that your menus should use a `containerElement` to use React-router Link though.

```
<MenuItem
   containerElement={<Link to="/profile" />}
.../>
```

Here is an example using the demo app on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/88ok152q08

Note the custom Menu in `menu.js`.

Also bear in mind that this menu will require a bit more work in order to adapt for mobile devices

Comment: Your answer does not help me. I need a example of how to create nested menus.

Comment: You have on in the material-ui documentation

Comment: Updated the answer with an example

Comment: Thanks, for the example! But more specifically, what I really want is to have the nested menu opened down the parent menu, and not to the right of the parent menu (like your example)

Comment: I'm afraid this will require writing a full custom React menu. Admin-on-rest uses Material-UI and I don't know about any component doing what you ask.